# Create dictionary from two list when values_list has several elements

Tags: python, dictionary

I'd like to make a dictionary with this variable (it has a weird format because it comes from a file):

```py
lines_no_comments = ['v:A,E,I,O,U', 'c:C,K,Q', 'b:B,P,D,M', 'z:C,Z,S']
```

so the desired output would be like:

```py
dic_final = {
    'v':['A','E','I','O','U'],
    'c':['C','K','Q'],
    'b':['B','P','D','M'],
    'z':['C','Z','S']
}
```

I've tried this:

```py
dic_final={}
for i in range(len(lines_no_comments)):
    keys = [char.strip() for char in lines_no_comments[i].split(':')[0]]
    values = [char.strip() for char in lines_no_comments[i].split(':')[1].split(',')]
    dic = dict(zip(keys, values))
    dic = {k:v for k,v in zip(keys, values)}
    dic_final.update(dic)
```

To ilustrate the code, in the first loop the variables keys and values store:

```py
keys = ['v']
values = ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']
```

The output of dic_final is

```py
dic_final = {'v': 'A', 'c': 'C', 'b': 'B', 'z': 'C'}
```

It seems that `dict(zip(keys, values))` is not adding the whole content of the vector dict. How can I do for adding the rest of values elements?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) setting `list` as a default value and loop through the strings updating the dictionary by splitting accordingly:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for i in lines_no_comments:
    k,v = i.split(':')
    d[k] = v.split(',')
```

---

```
print(d)

defaultdict(list,
            {'v': ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'],
             'c': ['C', 'K', 'Q'],
             'b': ['B', 'P', 'D', 'M'],
             'z': ['C', 'Z', 'S']})
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's understand what actually happens in your code.

```
    keys = [char.strip() for char in lines_no_comments[i].split(':')[0]]
    values = [char.strip() for char in lines_no_comments[i].split(':')[1].split(',')]
```

After first iteration you get

```
keys = ['v']
values = ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']
```

then let's understand how [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) works

> Returns an iterator of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th
>   element from each of the argument sequences or iterables. The iterator
>   stops when the shortest input iterable is exhausted.

So zipping keys and values will give you `('v', 'A')` as the shortest of these 2 has only one value.
Then making a dict out of result will give you only `{'v': 'A'}`. That's why your result dict has only one value per key.

As `keys` is actually a `key` you don't need to pack it into a list.
And `values` is already a list of values you don't need to mess with these two and just update your final dict with it
`dic_final[key]=values`.

Answer (score 2):

You can `split` twice (first on `:`, secondly on `,`) and pass into the `dict` constructor:

```
dic_final = dict((a, b.split(",")) for a, b in (x.split(":") for x in lines_no_comments))
print(dic_final)
#{'b': ['B', 'P', 'D', 'M'],
# 'c': ['C', 'K', 'Q'],
# 'v': ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'],
# 'z': ['C', 'Z', 'S']}
```

Comment: That inner part could be a generator rather than a list comprehension. `(x.split(":") for x in lines_no_comments)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it:

```
lines_no_comments  = ['v:A,E,I,O,U', 'c:C,K,Q', 'b:B,P,D,M', 'z:C,Z,S']
dic_final  = dict()
for line in lines_no_comments:
    key = line.split(':')[0]
    val = line.split(':')[1].split(',')
    dic_final.update({key:val})
```

Comment: You don't need to use `update` - you can just do `dic_final[key]=val`, but +1 for the plain old loop.

Answer (score 1):

Sure there are multiple ways to do the task, but I would like to actually answer the question: why the observed result?

This code mixes two approaches: do it in a single shot or item by item.

Without for loop (single shot approach), it would look like this:

```
keys = [line.split(':', 1)[0].strip() for line in lines_no_comments]
values = [line.split(':')[1].split(',').strip() for line in lines_no_comments]
dic_final = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

With the loop, it will be:

```
for line in lines_no_comments:
    key = line.split(':', 1)[0]
    values = line.split(':', 1)[1].split(',')
    dic_final[key] = value
```

Probably the best way to avoid it is to think though the algorithm before writing code. People usually aren't good at designing and implementing simultaneously